SSRS Custom security in SQL Server 2022 standard edition
I'm migrating from SQL Server 2016 to SQL Server 2022.
My organization had enterprise edition in the past which they used to set up dashboards and custom security for SSRS web portal.
They later downgraded to standard edition, but the custom security feature stayed and kept working.
Now I'm trying to set up the custom security feature on the new SQL Server 2022 machine.
I got to the point where the web portal redirects to the custom page. I'm able to log in but when I do I get this error:

The feature: "Scale-out deployment" is not supported in this edition of Reporting Services. (rsOperationNotSupported)

To the best of my understanding I'm not scaling our as there's only one report server that points to that database.
I'd love to hear your thoughts.
Thank you!
I tried setting it up as it is currently set up in the old server by editing the config files:
rsreportserver.config,  rssrvpolicy.config,
web.config
I've used this Microsoft article to make sure I didn't miss anything.
I backed up the ReportServer DB and ReportServerTempDB from the old server and restored them on the new server.
I configured both web urls in the Report Server Configuration Manager and it worked before I tried to set up custom security.

If you restored the database then the details of the old server will be in the SSRS configuration as well. Annoyingly (stupidly?) newer SSRS installs hide the scale out deployment menu in standard edition, so you have to delete it from the database. I, unfortunately, won't get a chance to explain how to do this till I'm back I  the office.

If I recall correctly, (it's been awhile) if you RESTORE the database and then set up (the new instance of) SSRS to use the restored database, the table dbo.Keys will still have the old server's key in it. This will cause SSRS to to think it is in scale-out mode, as there will now be 2 keys; your new server and the old.
Unfortunately Microsoft removed the scale-out deployment menu from the Reporting Service configuration manager in recent editions, when working with a non-enterprise edition of SQL Server. As a result you have to DELETE the old key from the table:
USE ReportServer;
GO
DELETE FROM dbo.Keys
WHERE MachineName = '<Name of Old Server>';
GO


Thank you for your answer.
Unfortunately, the dbo.Keys table is up to date, only containing the "new server name" in the machine key column and one more NULL record, which is created in installation and doesn't affect the deployment.
